# Scalar curvature and convexity

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry, curvature

Let $D \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a $C^2$ bounded domain and $n(x)$ the outer unit normal field. The scalar (mean) curvature is defined sometimes as
$$H(x)=\mathrm{div}\, n(x), \quad x\in \partial D$$
and sometimes as
$$H'(x)=\mathrm{div}_{\partial D}\, n(x) \quad x\in \partial D.$$
I have two questions:

1. Are the above definitions the same?
2. When $D$ is convex, is it true that $H(x)\ge 0$ at $\partial D$?

I'm looking for the proof or a reference where I can find such results.

Comment: What are the definitions you are given for the right side of the two displayed equations?

Comment: The first one is the Euclidean divergence while the second is the tangential divergence on the boundary.

Comment: What about taking the trace of the second fundamental form  as a definition to chek your two properties  ?: this is  the restriction of $n'(x)$ to the tangent space. Or $II(x) (u,v)= <n'x)u,v>$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this definition. Could you elaborate it in answer?